# possible to reference a jsonb_array_length in a where clause

Tags: postgresql, json

I am just starting to use some of the jsonb functionality in Postgres 9.4 (would love to move to 9.6) . I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    queryable_type, 
    jsonb_array_length(as_data->'users_who_like') as js_users_count 
FROM 
    queryables 
WHERE 
    queryable_type = 'Item' and jt_users_count > 1;
```

but I am unable to access jt_users_count in the where phrase but can like this:

```
SELECT
    queryable_type, 
    jsonb_array_length(as_data->'users_who_like') as js_users_count 
FROM 
    queryables 
WHERE
    queryable_type = 'Item' and jsonb_array_length(as_data->'users_who_like') > 1 
ORDER BY
    jsonb_array_length(as_data->'users_who_like') desc;
```

To be honest, this just seems a bit unusual and possibly wasteful. Is there a way for Postgres to only compute this once and use a reference to `jt_users_count`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the *standard* behaviour of SQL. SQL statements are (logically) processed in a certain specified order.

Following that order, the `WHERE` clause is executed *before* the `SELECT` one. That's why the `WHERE` clause *cannot access* the value of `js_users_count`: It has not yet been computed.

That's why your second query works, but your first one doesn't.

On the other hand, it is *possible* to have `js_users_count` on the `ORDER BY`, because that clause is processed *after* the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT
    queryable_type, 
    jsonb_array_length(as_data->'users_who_like') as js_users_count 
FROM 
    queryables 
WHERE
    queryable_type = 'Item' and jsonb_array_length(as_data->'users_who_like') > 1 
ORDER BY
    js_users_count desc;
```

Don't be afraid about a certain computation being done twice. It can be either optimized (as some kind of common subexpression elimination optimization) or its impact is completely neglectable in the overall performance of a query.

If you want to *really make sure* that an expression is *not* evaluated twice, you can use one (often annoying) feature of PostgreSQL CTE: the fact that [they're optimization fences](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/) (i.e.: they won't be *inlined*, or converted to subqueries in the final statement):

```
WITH q1 AS
(
    SELECT
        queryable_type, 
        jsonb_array_length(as_data->'users_who_like') as js_users_count 
    FROM 
        queryables 
    WHERE
        queryable_type = 'Item'
)
SELECT
     *
FROM
    q1 
WHERE
    js_users_count > 1 
ORDER BY
    js_users_count desc;
```

This will create a (virtual temporary) table `q1` with the already computed values of `jsonb_array_length`. I would only do this kind of thing if the function used takes a very long time to execute (has a very high cost), and there's evidence that it's actually called twice (you can check with some [`RAISE DEBUG`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) statements in the function itself, if it's been written by you).

References:

- [SQL Query Order of Operations](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm)
- [You Can Reference Your Derived SELECT Columns In Your ORDER BY Clause In SQL](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2684-you-can-reference-your-derived-select-columns-in-your-order-by-clause-in-sql.htm)
- [SQL Programming: Understanding the Logical Order of Operations in SELECT statements](http://blog.aajtech.com/blog/sql-programming-understanding-the-logical-order-of-operations-in-select-statements/)
- [Order of execution of a Query](https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution)