# Reference ARRAY_AGG - length in WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

My question is similar to [possible reference jsonb_array_length in a where clause](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/177910/269368), however I cannot use `ORDER BY`.

I have following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS games
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  username CHARACTER VARYING(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  ...
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS game_users
(
    game_id INTEGER REFERENCES games (id) NOT NULL,
    user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users (id) NOT NULL,
    joined_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (game_id, user_id)
);
```

I want to query games that have less than 4 participants.

```
SELECT gm.*,
  array_agg(usr.id) AS users_id,
  array_agg(gmUsr.joined_at) AS users_joined,
  array_agg(usr.username) AS users_username
FROM games AS gm
  LEFT JOIN game_users AS gmUsr ON gmUsr.game_id = gm.id
  LEFT JOIN users AS usr ON gmUsr.user_id = usr.id
WHERE cardinality(array_length(users_id)) < 4
GROUP BY gm.id
```

I already [saw in an answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/177911/269368) that the `WHERE` clause is executed before the SELECT one. So my query will not work.
However I want to keep `GROUP BY` user `id` because I want aggregated data as:

```typescript
type GamesJoinedUsers = {
  id: number,
  users_id: number[],
  users_joined: Date[],
  users_username: string[],
}
```

How to query such data at least somehow?

Is it possible to do it in one query without subquery?

Comment: You need to use `having` to apply filters on the result of aggregate functions

Comment: `HAVING` also evaluated before the SELECT clause https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-having/

Comment: That is not true. Try it! And rely on the real documentation.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe It most definitely is true: `HAVING` is evaluated before `SELECT`, this is part of the SQL standard. Here's a simple proof https://dbfiddle.uk/ZsF7NFLp

Comment: @Charlieface You are right, I should have been more careful. Still, `HAVING` is the solution to the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you just need to replace your `WHERE` clause with a `HAVING` clause like this:

```
HAVING
  COUNT(isr.id) < 4
```

The `HAVING` clause is the appropriate place for a filter that needs to apply to an aggregated result.  In this case, you want a filter on the number of users per game, which is an aggregate result given your `GROUP BY`.  Therefore, use `HAVING`.

Comment: Thanks! This works. Using `HAVING` with `cardinality(array_length(users_id))` still does not work. However the trick with `COUNT(usr.id)` is more elegant in this case!